# Correctness of adding int32 and int64 in IL

Tags: .net, cil, ilasm

Working on custom interpreter of IL code I've noticed that the following code can be compiled by `ilasm.exe` and executed well:

```
.locals init (int32 x, int64 y, int64 z)

ldloc x
ldloc y
add
stloc z
```

But in the ECMA-335 (unfortunately I can't insert a link to html, only [pdf](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) seems to be available) I see that combination of `int32` and `int64` is not supported for binary operations (as shown in the table Table III.2: Binary Numeric Operations).

Moreover adding `float32` and `int64` also can be compiled and executed.

Is it a mistake in the .net runtime?

How to check what combinations are really correct and should be supported?

Comment: Compiling is one thing, did you try to `peverify` the resulting assembly?

Comment: @thehennyy I did compile and... execute.

Comment: Can you give it a try? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/peverify-exe-peverify-tool, also have a look at the remarks section.

Comment: I actually created this code and executed it, exe works fine, but failed with PEVerify `[found Int32][expected Long] Unexpected type on the stack.`
If PEVerify fails, it might violate memory access constraints\ willn't run on any compliant implementation of the CLI.

I think in this case we can consider this behavior as unspecified.
By II.3 (ECMA-335)
`The verification process is very stringent. There are many programs that will pass validation, but will
fail verification. The VES cannot guarantee that these programs do not access memory or resources to which they are not granted access`